# Cannot use findAll(Specifications<T>, Pageable) method for JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Cannot use findAll(Specifications, Pageable) method for JpaSpecificationExecutor repository.
I have the repository interface as:

```
package com.task.task.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.task.task.domain.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {
}
```

Whenever I am calling **employeeRepository.findAll(specifications, pageable);** This error is thrown:

```
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException",
    "message": "Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications]: No default constructor found;
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications.<init>()",
    "path": "/api/task/employee"
```

This is stacktrace:

```
2018-01-17 14:41:29.816 ERROR 12132 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications.<init>()] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

Full code : https://github.com/SanketKD/SpecificationExecutor

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp111")
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "employee_id")
  private Long employeeId;

  @Column(name = "ename", length = 20)
  private String ename;

  @Column(name = "hire_date")
  private Date hireDate;

  @Column(name = "salary")
  private Long salary;

  @Column(name = "skills", length = 30)
  private String skills;

// getters setters
```

Service:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.task.task.domain.Employee;
import com.task.task.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

  private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

  @Autowired
  public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
    this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
  }

  public Employee getEmployee(Long employeeId) {
    return employeeRepository.findOne(employeeId);
  }

  public Page<Employee> getEmployees(Specifications<Employee> specifications, Pageable pageable) {
    return employeeRepository.findAll(specifications, pageable);
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.task.task.domain.Employee;
import com.task.task.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/task/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

  private final EmployeeService employeeService;

  @Autowired
  public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{employeeId:[0-9]\\d*}")
  public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable Long employeeId) {
    return this.employeeService.getEmployee(employeeId);
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Page<Employee> getEmployees(Specifications<Employee> specifications, Pageable pageable) {
    return this.employeeService.getEmployees(specifications, pageable);
  }
}
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.task.task.domain.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {
}
```

Comment: Add default constructor in your Entity Employee

Comment: Add your dependencies.

Comment: @SanketKD - Could you please share your code or `Specifications<Employee>` specifications or `EmployeeSpecs.employeeName(name)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you get is not related to the repository, it's because you mapped `Specification<Employee>` in your controller. This is not possible because Spring has no idea how to "parse" the incoming request to `Specification<Employee>`. It will try to construct the `Specification` by calling the default constructor, but since there is no default constructor, it throws an exception in stead.

Rather than mapping it in your controller, you need to use a proper request body (or parameters) and create the `Specification` either in your controller, or your service.

Using **Spring boot 2.x.x**, you can do that with:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Employee> getEmployees(
        // Just plain parameters
        @RequestParam String name,
        @RequestParam int page,
        @ResuestParam int limit) {
    // Creating the specification
    Specification<Employee> spec = Specification.where(EmployeeSpecs.employeeName(name));
    // Creating the Pageable as well
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, limit);
    return this.employeeService.getEmployees(specifications, pageable);
}
```

Using **Spring boot 1.x.x**, [`Specification.where()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#where-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-) is called [`Specifications.where()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specifications.html#where-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-). Additionally, the [`PageRequest.of(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-) static method doesn't exist, and you should use the [`new PageRequest(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#PageRequest-int-int-) constructor.

Comment: Could you please share import statements? As Specification has been deprecated ?

Comment: @PAA `Specification` itself is not deprecated. `Specifications.where()` however is deprecated, and moved to `Specification.where()` in stead. I've changed my code to work with Spring boot 2.x.x.

Comment: In my case I get error `The method where(Specification<T>) in the type Specification is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Employee>)`, Created question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131227/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-create-query-for-method